# Is there another and better way to filter by years in SQL using php of this?

Tags: php, sql

I have this code to filter by years. It's working, but I want to know if there is another way to do it.

This is my code :

```
$filter_values = '2012,2019,2018';

// sql query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE ";

// convert string to array
$str_arr = explode(",", $filter_values);

// check if is first loop
$first = true;

// loop to create SQL query filter
foreach ($str_arr as $row) {
    if ($first == true) {
        $query .= " (`date` LIKE '" . $row .= "' ";
    } else {
        $query .= " OR `date` LIKE '" . $row .= "' ";
    }

    $first = false;
}

$query .= ")";
```

The final SQL query will be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE (`date` LIKE '2012' 
       OR `date` LIKE '2019' 
       OR `date` LIKE '2018')
```

Comment: What's the type of column `date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `like` for dates.  `like` is an operation on strings, not date.

One simple method is to use `year()` and `in`:

```
where year(date) in (2012, 2019, . . . )
```

You are selecting a lot of data, so it probably not important that this cannot use an index.  In other circumstances, ranges are better:

```
where (date >= '2012-01-01' and date < '2013-01-01') or
      (date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2020-01-01') or
      . . .
```

because this formula could use an index if available.